# Where does the rotation matrix come from?

Tags: matrices, rotations

I looked through many different books, but none of them explain how they derive the matrix below. They just state it as is and move on. Can you explain, please.

$ \begin{bmatrix} R(\vec e_1), R(\vec e_1) \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} cos x & - sinx \\ sinx & cosx \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Take the unit vectors $(1,0),(0,1)$ and rotate them in the plane by an angle $x$. Then you can figure out the matrix $R$ from its actions on this basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It comes from consideration of the transformed positions of the unit vectors

Comment: What does rotating do to $e_1$? Spins it around the unit circle and wherever the vector ends up, it's still a unit vector  $\vec e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} cosx \\ sinx \end{bmatrix}$. Thus it's the first column of the rotation matrix. Like that?

Comment: right... then the matrix also has to work for $e_2$, which is the second column.

Comment: But can $(1, 0)$ when rotated end up anywhere other than $(1, 0)$, though?

Comment: sure, why not? If I rotate $(1,0)$ through 30 degrees it maps to $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}2, \frac 1 2)$

Comment: @Goos. Looks fine to me and leaves a bit of room for the question setter to think. Just as it should.

Comment: @Joffan, I tried thinking about the second column of the matrix, but wasn't able to come up with anything. Any hints?

Comment: The rotation matrix works on the whole plane, and the same 30-degree rotation I talked about before maps $(0,1)$ to $(-\frac 1 2, \frac{\sqrt{3}} 2)$